# Autocomplete for delimited phrases in the file?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

Is it somehow possible to autocomplete a whole phrase which has been delimited from earlier on in the file?

For example the following phrase exists:

```
Agenda:
    - Item: [The first item on the agenda]
```

And I want to be able to type `[The f` and have the remainder of the phrase appear in the autocomplete pop up.

Comment: This is not possible, as Sublime's contextual autocomplete only works by individual words. If you have frequent phrases you use, you can define a [completions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html) file.

Comment: it's possible to write a plugin to do it - is this just Plain Text syntax?